# Send the contents of a CSV as a table in an email?

Tags: python, email, html-email

How can I send the contents of a CSV as a table in an email using Python?

Example file:

```
name,age,dob

xxx,23,16-12-1990

yyy,15,02-11-1997
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `smtplib`:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
# just an example, you format it usng html
html = "<html><body><table><tr><td>name</td><td><age></td><td>dob</td<tr></table></body></html>"
msg1 = MIMEText(html,'html')
msg = MIMEMultipart("test")
msg['Subject'] = "Name of subject"
msg['From'] = "your@email.com"
msg['To'] = "reciver@gmail.com"
msg.attach(msg1)

server = smtplib.SMTP("smpt_server",port)         # example smtplib.smtp("smtp.gmail.com,587)
server.starttls()

server.login("your@gmail.com","login_password")
server.sendmail("your@email.com","reciver@gmail.com",msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

better you can do:

```
msg1 = MIMEText(f.open("file.csv").read())
msg.attach(msg1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Check [this](http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/send-mail-through-gmail-with-python/) link.

Just pass your csv as third argument to `server.sendmail()` method